# Transitive Object Libraries in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, compilation, build-system, object-library

**Question: Is it possible to join multiple object libraries into a single larger object library?**

Consider the following simple project. `libA.cpp` is compiled into an object library `LibA.Obj`, and `libB.cpp` is compiled into an object library `LibB.Obj`. I want to have an object library, `LibAB.Obj`, that consists of both `LibA.Obj` and `LibB.Obj`, and I want to link against it to produce a single shared library.

```
MyProject
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── src
    ├── libA.cpp
    └── libB.cpp
```

If I want to link two libraries, A and B, into a single unit, I can do that by declaring them as object libraries:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)

project(ObjectLibExample)

add_library(LibA.Obj OBJECT src/libA.cpp)
add_library(LibB.Obj OBJECT src/libB.cpp)

add_library(LibAB SHARED $<TARGET_OBJECTS:LibA.Obj> $<TARGET_OBJECTS:LibB.Obj>)
```

This works as expected, and everything builds.

For reasons I will soon explain, I would like to merge multiple object libraries together into a single unit:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)

project(ObjectLibExample)

add_library(LibA.Obj OBJECT src/libA.cpp)
add_library(LibB.Obj OBJECT src/libB.cpp)

# Using LibAB.Obj as a source should be equivilant to using both LibA.Obj and LibB.Obj
add_library(LibAB.Obj OBJECT $<TARGET_OBJECTS:LibA.Obj> $<TARGET_OBJECTS:LibB.Obj>)

add_library(LibAB SHARED $<TARGET_OBJECTS:LibAB.Obj>)
```

Here, `LibAB.Obj` should be an object library collecting the sources of both `LibA.Obj` and `LibB.Obj`.

For some reason, CMake acts as though `LibAB.Obj` provides no sources, and the build fails.

- **Why does this happen?**
- **Is this a bug?**
- **What workarounds are there?**

[image]

## Motivation / Background

I am currently working on re-organizing an existing project to have a modular structure. It will have modules A, B, and C, each of which will have submodules.

You can imagine the directory structure looking like this:

```
MyProject
├── A
│   ├── A1
│   ├── A2
│   └── A3
├── B
│   ├── B1
│   ├── B2
│   └── B3
└── C
    ├── C1
    ├── C2
    └── C3
```

Each submodule represents a library that forms a part of a greater whole, and the build system should link everything together into a single library at the end.

The reason for this structure is twofold:

- each submodule forms a cohesive unit. It has it's own tests, benchmarks, and example code
- submodules should provide a clean API for their functionality, even if the internals are kind of hairy.

For example, `MyProject/A/A1` looks like this:

```
MyProject/A/A1
├── bench
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── examples
├── src
└── test
```

My initial plan was to have each module contain an object library linking all of it's respective submodules, with all modules being statically linked together at root to produce a single library, `MyProject.so`.

Each submodule would also produce a library specific to that submodule (eg, `MyProject/A/A1` would produce `MyProject.A.A1.so`), against which tests, benchmark code, and examples would be linked. This would allow faster iteration, without needing to re-build the entire project.

Unfortunately, this initial approach failed, for the reasons discussed above.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation of `add_library(OBJECT)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#object-libraries):

> An object library compiles source files but does not archive or link their object files into a library.
>
> [...]
>
> Object libraries may contain only sources that compile, header files, and other files that would not affect linking of a normal library (e.g. .txt).

You haven't provided any sources that would compile, so a fatal error indicating that the object library isn't used in the intended way is expected.

A workaround possible starting cmake 3.12 would be to create an `INTERFACE` library and linking the object libraries with `INTERFACE` visibility.

```
add_library(LibAB INTERFACE)
target_link_libraries(LibAB.Obj INTERFACE LibA.Obj LibB.Obj)
```

```
add_library(LibAB SHARED)
target_link_libraries(LibAB PRIVATE LibAB.Obj)
```

This does prevent you from using `$<TARGET_OBJECTS:LibAB.Obj>` though.

Comment: The `INTERFACE` library should be declared as `LibAB.Obj`. As it stands, it looks like you declared `LibAB` twice, once as an `INTERFACE` library and once as a `SHARED` library. I would edit your answer myself, but StackOverflow requires that edits be at least 6 characters and that change would be only three characters.